# how do I retrieve data which has value 1 as the column name and ignore the data which has value of 0 in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a new project using php and mysql 

 after inserting the values I want to retrieve them as the column name 
I'm using this table

```
    CREATE TABLE categories (
ID INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT 
,action INT(1) DEFAULT '0'
,comedy INT(1) DEFAULT '0'
,drama INT(1) DEFAULT '0'
,mystery   INT(1) DEFAULT '0'

)
```

values are either 0 or 1 , I want to retrieve the value 1 as the column name like if action and mystery has value = 1 I want to display them alone 

 what I'm having a hard time is displaying them as the name and only show value 1

edit as requested some sample data 
when I try to get the values they appear 0 or 1

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM categories WHERE ID = $id");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo '  
<div class="categories">

'.$row["action"].' -
'.$row["comedy"].' -
'.$row["drama"].' -
 '.$row["mystery"].' </div>'
```

what I want is the 1 to be named as the column name

Comment: Please provide some sample data and example results

Comment: _"Sample data"_ as in the current data that is in your table. _"Example result"_ as in, _"I want the result to look like this..."_.

Comment: Doesn't look like the most optimal database design. If you wanted to add a new category you'd need to add a new column to your database? I think it would be better if your `categories` table had an id and a name column. As for your problem, use something like `if $row["action"] == 1 then echo "action"` etc.

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost meaningless, and probably best omitted. And I agree with kerbholz; this design appears far from optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over array keys of first row to get column names. But better option is to use ORM schemes and get titles from there.

One solution (but not recomennded, because you must iterate over all columns you retrieve from table). And you show also ID column name.

```
echo '<div class="categories">' . implode(array_keys($row), ' - ') . '</div>';
```

Second thing is that your design of database is very bad. I don't know exact purpose but you should have for categories only two columns: ID and name.

Comment: The second thing is the first thing

Comment: would having only two columns help in search feather ? I'm planing on searching by categories by using 
`SELECT * FROM categories WHERE drama = 1`
edit typo

Comment: Yes, you should search for specific categories like `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name='drama'`. You don't need to create new column for next category then.

Answer (score 1):

after looking for the optimal table thanks to  kerbh0lz and tajniak I found it

create table statement 
`create table categories (categoryid int(1), category varchar(20) );`
inserting new genres 
`insert into categories values
(1 ,'action'),
(2 ,'comedy'),
(3 ,'drama'),
(4 ,'mystery');`